# Different kind of projections from 4D space

Tags: geometry

I'm studying some packing lattices and landed to the $D_4$ one. This is highly connected to the 24-cell in 4D, since representing its vertices (for for the first and the second shell).

Actually I was trying to understand a bit better the 24-cell, and I found in many places some projections from 4D to the 3D world.

What's is a bit confusing to me is the different kind of projections one could use: vertex-first, cell-first etc.

I've googled a lot without finding any real explanation between them.
Can you help me in understanding them better, or point to me to some books or links which could explain them clearly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You turn a body this way or that way, and depending on that, obtain different projections; there is nothing more to it. Do you need an entire book to reiterate this simple fact?

Comment: I thought it was something specific to higher dimensions. Now you explained it to me, it's simple indeed. Nothing is simple until understood.

Comment: No need to go for higher dimensions. Think of 3D: what is the planar projection of a cube? Maybe a square, or maybe a hexagon.

Comment: Thanks, it's clear to me now.

Comment: Raise it to an answer, so I can vote for it, if you want.

Comment: Nah, that's too trivial.